# Insert value in MySQL fields using node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api, rest

In my MySQL database I have three fields (selected_product_id, quantity, user_id). Instead of manually entering a value for the selected_product_id body from postman, I want to run a MySQL query and pull product name and automatically assign the id of the product to the selected_product_id field.

```
//Controller.js file
 

addProduct: (req, res) =>{
    const body = req.body;
    let errors = {};
    pool.query('SELECT name from products WHERE name = ?', [body.product_name], (error, results) => {
      if(error){
        console.log(error);
      }
      if(results.length === 0){
        errors.message = 'Product not found'
      }
      else if(results.length > 0){
        pool.query('SELECT id, name, maker from products WHERE name = ?', [body.product_name], (error, results)=>{
          if(error){
            console.log(error)
          }
          req.body.selected_product_id = //This is where I want to automatically assign the id value of the product
        })
      }
      if(Object.keys(errors).length > 0){
        return res.status(400).json(errors);
      }

      addUser(body, (err, results) =>{
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
          return res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: 'Database connection error'
          })
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
          success: true,
          message: 'Request sent to [username]',
          data: results
        })
      })

    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnt do that in JavaScript, but rather in the database itself. Theres a neat little thing you can add to get this effect, its called "AUTO_INCREMENT". When you create a new Table, you can give it that keyword.

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    product_Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    quantity int,
    user_Id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_Id)
);
```

Cheers

Comment: Yeah I understand. However, what I am trying to do is each product already has a unique id. I just want to assign that id to the selected_product_id field. I changed the name in my code so it makes sense in terms of what I am trying to accomplish.